# <h:selectOneListbox disabled=true causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, jsf

I have JSF 1.1 page in which I have a `<h:selectOneListbox`. When I set property disabled=true, selected value in `<h:selectOneListbox` becomes null upon submitting the page.

```
<h:selectOneListbox size="1" id="prod"  disabled="#{mybean.disable}"
```

How can I make sure value selected is not null even if property is set to disabled=true.

Thanks

Comment: why are you disabling the list? if you don't want to get selected anything why you are keeping that in your code?

Comment: I am disabling the list because when user presses confirmation button then he is not allowed to change anything in the page and hence I am disabling list along with other components in the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the `disabled` attribute is set on a HTML input element, then it is not only uneditable, but it would also **not** send its name=value pair as request parameter to the server. That explains why the server retrieves `null`s for them.

If you want to make it uneditable, but still want to send its name=value pair as request parameter to the server, then you should be using `readonly` instead.

```html
<h:someInput ... readonly="true">
```