# NullPointer when HTML input is disabled

Tags: java, javascript, html, servlets, nullreferenceexception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [<h:selectOneListbox disabled=true causing NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672614/hselectonelistbox-disabled-true-causing-nullpointerexception)

I didn't really know what to searc for, and it does sound a little bit strange to me.

If I am disabling an input `type=textfield` item with

```
$('#kundennr').attr("disabled","disabled");
```

and my form is calling an Servlet, in which I want to read the value of my field `kundennr`
it gives me a `Nullpointerexeption`. But if I let the field enabled, it gives me the Value of the field

```
request.getParameter("kundennummer");
```

So how can I disable an input field, without having an `nullpointer` in my Java Servlet?

Comment: You can try to copy the value into another field (not necessarily a textfield) and set it to display none or so (invoked before submission).

Comment: I just Found the anwer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672614/hselectonelistbox-disabled-true-causing-nullpointerexception ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A disabled element in the DOM is ignored upon submission, you'll want to set the *readonly* attribute instead.

Please keep in mind that anything that is submitted from the client might be subject to manipulation (e.g. I could alter that number and send it to you regardless of you making it readonly), so make sure to validate any critical information server-side before acting upon it!

Answer (score -1):

Disabled input fields are not sent. You probably want to use a hidden field. What you are trying to accomplish? Try readonly="readonly" - should be posted but still sent with headers - thats if the info needs to be visible in the form - if not then the hidden field is best.

Comment: Please do not repeat word for word what other posters said